# add style to html without angularjs loading them

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using `ui-router` of angularjs in my SPA. When i add an style to my view pages, angularjs loads them when switching to than view. Thats actually pretty cool that it can be done in runtime.

The problem is i do not want it to do so. for example i want to use bootstrap css in my view. it is already inserted in the main page, so it is not needed to get loaded again form child view. but for my IDE to auto-complete class names, it is needed to be added to html page of subview.

Is there any way to ask Angularjs to ignore `Head` part and just load `Body` part of my html?

Comment: Put ng-app on body tag or bootstrap(document.body), or use ng-non-bindable on unintended tags

Comment: @Mateutek i`m using intellij idea

Comment: @YOU ng-non-bindable is for when u don`t want angular to parse expressions in a tag. it does not stop it from being loaded.